# how to bind elements from one container to call member func on another container

Tags: c++, boost-bind, stl-algorithm

I've two containers - one is of vector type and the other one is of unordered_set.

Now, I want to check if any of element from the vector exists in the unordered_set or not - something like **find_first_of** does - and return true/false accordingly.

Now, since I wanted to exploit find of unordered_set, I's thinking to use **any_of(vector_container.begin(), vector_container.end(), predicate)** instead of using find_first_of.

Is there a way that I can use **boost::bind** to bind elements from the vector to find from the unordered_set so that I don't have to write the predicate class?

Comment: Why do you want to use Boost.Bind and not a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)? (That is, `[&](vector_container::value_type const& v) {return set_container.find(v) != set_container.end(); }`)

Comment: Because I cannot use C++0x

Comment: I now realize that even any_of is not available in C++98. Is there any other similar algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with `find()` is very awkward, but there is an alternative: you can use unordered_set's `count()` function:

```
boost::algorithm::any_of(
    vector_container.begin(), vector_container.end(),
    boost::bind(&boost::unordered_set<int>::count, boost::ref(set_container), _1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one slightly lazy predicate, using `count(n) == 0` as "non-existence" (and "== 1" as "existence"):

```
boost::bind(
    std::equal_to<std::size_t>(),
    boost::bind(std::mem_fun(&std::unordered_set<int>::count), &s, _1),
    0)
```

This takes advantage of the [composability of `boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5f55%5f0/libs/bind/bind.html#nested%5fbinds). If you're a little more verbose you can substitute `find(n) == end()` or `find(n) != end()` instead.

Here's a little demo, removing all the elements that are in a set from a vector:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int> s { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::vector<int> v  { 2, 5, 9, 1 };

    v.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            v.begin(), v.end(),
            boost::bind(
                std::equal_to<std::size_t>(),
                boost::bind(std::mem_fun(&std::unordered_set<int>::count), &s, _1),
                1)),
        v.end());

    for (int n : v) { std::cout << n << "\n"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::any_of(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(&std::set<int>::find, &s, boost::lambda::_1) != s.end());`